# Get XML elements and replace the values as string?

Tags: c#, xml, string

Get an XML element from a loaded XML file, I believe I need to modify my logic as I need to get the element value as a string and not Descendants, then replace the value as a custom one and then I need to put the XML as a string message i.e. doc.ToString();

Please advise how to do this to get the elements value as a string from the loaded XML and then replace that value in memory?

```
string filePath = @"C:\FileMessageTemplates\Outright\"; //File path
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath + "First_Test_1.xml"); //Loads document 
string catsId = doc.Descendants("CatsId").SingleOrDefault().ToString(); //Want to get element CatsId here and then replace the value, then save it as string
doc.ToString();
```

Here is the XML

```
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemS-instance" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <FeedTest>
    <ActionId xsi:nil="true" />
    <ReplyToMessageId>12345</ReplyToMessageId>
    <Source>PAPER</Source>
    <Condition />
    <FixingRate xsi:nil="true" />
    <CatsId>TAAH20181105X0000579</CatsId>
  </FeedTest>
</Test>
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of the XML

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss provided the XML

Comment: My guess should work for that XML...I did NOT test it...

Comment: Doesnt work I need a simple solution mate

Comment: I added a simple example - I parsed as a string but your load should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Find the descendant with name 'CatsId' in the xml. Then replace the value on the resulting XElement. This will update the element value inside the in-memory document.

```
string filePath = @"C:\FileMessageTemplates\Outright\First_Test_1.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath); 

// Get the proper element (assuming one exists, without namespace)
XElement catsIdElement = doc.Descendants("CatsId").SingleOrDefault(); 

// Replace the value
catsIdElement.Value = "My new value";

// Tadaa, updated CatsId value
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the sample of the XML this is the best guess.

```
string filePath = @"C:\FileMessageTemplates\Outright\"; //File path
string path = Path.Combine(filePath ,"First_Test_1.xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path); //Loads document 
var list = doc.Root.Elements("CatsId")
                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                   .ToList();

foreach (string value in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
// just the first one:
string catidstring = (string)list.FirstOrDefault();
```

NOTE: IF there is only one it can be simpler:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _xml = @"<Test xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemS-instance' xmlns:user='urn:my-scripts' xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'>
  <FeedTest>
    <ActionId xsi:nil='true' />
    <ReplyToMessageId>12345</ReplyToMessageId>
    <Source>PAPER</Source>
    <Condition />
    <FixingRate xsi:nil='true' />
    <CatsId>TAAH20181105X0000579</CatsId>
  </FeedTest>
</Test>";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(_xml);
        var catIdText = doc.Root.Element("FeedTest").Element("CatsId").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(catIdText);

        // update or use XPath to update...
        doc.Root.Element("FeedTest").Element("CatsId").Value = catIdText+"Happy day";
        //doc.XPathSelectElement("//Test/FeedTest/CatsId").Value =catIdText+"Happy day";
        var catIdUpdatedText = doc.Root.Element("FeedTest").Element("CatsId").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(catIdUpdatedText);

        // save it again:
        string filePath = @"C:\FileMessageTemplates\Outright\"; //File path
        string path = Path.Combine(filePath ,"First_Test_NEW.xml");
        xdoc.Save(path);
    }
}
```